# Religious symbolism of the Telmarines?

Tags: symbolism, c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia, religion

The religious symbolism in C.S. Lewis's Narnia books is well known and, in many cases, very clear: [Aslan *is* Jesus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117792/31394), the Calormenes are a very stereotypical portrayal of Muslims, [the Dwarfs *may* represent Jews](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/801/17), and so on.

What about the Telmarines, as seen in *Prince Caspian*? They rule over Narnia and banish the talking creatures and dwarfs, hags, etc. to the mere legends that they are in our own world. **Do they represent anything in the symbolic Lewisian theology?** Atheists, perhaps?

Comment: The Ancient Romans morphing into the Roman Catholic Church :) Am attempting a justification.

Comment: "the Calormenes are a very stereotypical portrayal of Muslims"? Can you justify or reference this? In my understanding, the Calormenes are way too early to be Muslims.

Comment: I would associate the Calormenes with people in that area, or India, etc., but long before Islam.

Comment: Perhaps atheists? I'd have to think about it more, and I'd be curious for your thoughts on it, but: they don't believe in the 'old stories' but are secretly a bit afraid, they believe in 'progress' (think schools that Aslan tears down, the deforestation, and the bridge over Beruna), and we never hear about any particular god-like figure that they worship. However, there's a part of me that wonders if that position was kinda taken up by Eustace's parents?

Comment: @heather Could well be! For Eustace's parents, see [this question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8406/17).